# Do function on only 1 Control of NumericUpDown

Tags: c#, controls, tooltip, numericupdown

I let a supertooltip (from DotNetBar) appear on every control of NumericUpDown. But I only need a supertooltip on the TextBox of NumericUpDown. Here is my current code:

```
foreach (Control c in NumericUpDown.Controls)
{
    NumericUpDownToolTip.SetSuperTooltip(c, NumericUpDownSuperToolTip);
}

//Declarations:
//NumericUpDownToolTip is a SuperToolTip from DotNetBar
//NumericUpDownSuperToolTip is the configuration of the SuperToolTip (for example: the text of the tooltip)
```

So how do I set the tooltip only on the textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your foreach to be this:

```
foreach (Control c in NumericUpDown.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the old fashioned way:

```
foreach (Control c in NumericUpDown.Controls)
{
    if (!(c is TextBox)) continue;
    NumericUpDownToolTip.SetSuperTooltip(c, NumericUpDownSuperToolTip);
}
```

Or use LINQ to accomplish the same

```
var controls = NumericUpDown.Controls.Where(c => c is TextBox);

foreach (Control c in controls)
   NumericUpDownToolTip.SetSuperTooltip(c, NumericUpDownSuperToolTip);
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer and good explanation! But I prefer the shorter code.